# Wireshark Decoding TLS Encripted Data From My Own Computer

Tags: tls, wireshark

I'm trying to analyse the data that is being sent between my own computer and a web server via HTTPS.

I'm using Wireshark to examine the packets, however I can't see any of the data as it has been encrypted using TLSv1.2. Please note, there is no HTTP option for the website, it by default redirects to HTTPS if you attempt HTTP so I cannot prevent the webserver encrypting the data.

How do I configure Wireshark to be able to decrypt these packets so I can see the data being sent?

Please note, that the computer I'm running Wireshark on, is the same computer I'm attempting to decode the data for. I have access to all the SSL keys.